# Data Retention in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development

I had uploaded a document in document library and had given data retention period as 1 day then I ran two timer jobs for information management policy and expiration policy.

That document got deleted when I tried it for first time.

Now when I am trying to do it again its not happening.

Comment: you can instead use something like SharePoint designer workflow to delete an item from a list or library after certain expiry period

Answer (score 1):

Just write following workflow in SharePoint designer and then you are good to go!

[image]

This workflow starts when the item is created and remains in the loop until expiry date crosses and once expiry date is crossed the item is deleted.

Here you can add as many days to item created date as your expiry date.

**Update:**
For SharePoint 2010 Do As Directed

1.) Click any where in the area of the stage then you will see an orange line,click on the line and press enter you will see a textbox

[image]

[image]

2.) Type Add in the text box and press enter and choose the second option "Add Time to date"

[image]

[image]

3.)Click on minutes link and select days

[image]

4.)Then click on the date link, you will see fx button click on that and you will see a dialog box,just choose the field which you want and click ok

[image]

5.) Create local variable in the workflow as shown below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank u so mch :) but m not able to write that comment Add 0 months ,1 days to current item:created (output to variable:expiry date) Please help me out with step by step approach as m a fresher i m not able to figure out the solution.would be greatfull if u help me out with this.

Comment: are you working with SharePoint designer workflow and have you created a list workflow on your list

Comment: Thank u for ur help.. yea m working with sharepoint designer workflow and i havnt created a list workflow so far m very new to this.this is my first assignment. i m following ur steps but still m not figure out if not condition in sharepoint designer 2010.M still stuck there.Could you please assist me with that ? and put the entire steps.

Comment: yup i got it how to do that thank u for ur help :)

Comment: if you found my post useful please up vote it and once you have a reputation of 15 mark it as answer:)